Polynomials in $k[x,y]$ where $f(x,y) = 0$ iff $x=y=0$
If $f(x) = x^n - a$ has no root in $k$, we have that $x^n - ay^n = 0$ iff $x=y=0$.
However, there are fields that are not algebraically closed where we can't find a polynomial of the form $x^n - a$ with no roots.
Is there something that works for all fields which are not algebraically closed?
edit: If $k$ is not algebraically closed, we have an $f(x)$ which has degree $>=2$ and is irreducible. I have tried looking into functional equations like $f(x)*f(y) - f(0)^2$ but have failed to find anything that works.
This question is just a curiosity related to a homework problem where we construct varieties with a finite set of points over $\mathbb{R}^2$ with an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$.

Please state what you've considered and where you're stuck in trying to determine existence or nonexistence. Like this, it just looks like you're asking us to do your homework.

Let $g(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial with degree $n>1$. Try $f(x,y) = y^n g(x/y)$.

@Basics That works!
